# Mock sequelize-typescript model

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, chai, sinon, sequelize-typescript

I'm trying to mock a `sequelize-typescript` model to test whether a procedure with a side effect, which updates a model does it correctly, without a need to connect to a database. Since it is not possible to create a model instance without Sequelize instance, I'm stuck. I found multiple sequelize mocking packages non of which have typescript DefinitelyTyped typings.

```js
describe("A test", function () {
  let sandbox: SinonSandbox
  let user: User

  before(function () {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox()
    sandbox.stub(User, "findOne").callsFake(() => user)
  })

  beforeEach(function () {
    user = new User(userProps) // This is not allowed
  })

  it("should test side effects", function () {
      testFunction()
      expect(user.property).to.be.equal(someValue)
  })
})
```

Comment: Can't you mock the whole user object with jest.mock("../src/models/user.model")?